# Regex to match a repeating pattern of a number followed by any kind of delimiter?

Tags: c++, regex

I have a text file that consisted only with numbers separated by delimiters. The delimiter can be comma, space, line break etc other than number.

```
1, 2, 3, 4 
1 2 3 4
1|2|3|4
1hello2hello3hello4
```

I am looking for a regex to match this repeating pattern throughout the text file. And the expected outcome will be either "match found" or "match not found".

Clarification, if the text started with a number and a space as the delimiter, the entire text should be repeated with this pattern. So if somewhere in the text there's something like this:

```
12 34 56,78
```

The match should break and return no match found.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: your delimiter could be a letter, let's say 0a1a2...?

Comment: I just want to check for this pattern to flag the file. I will have user upload their text files and I only need this kind of file while rejecting all the others.

Comment: @xxce10xx the delimiter will have no number

Comment: only integers or it could be accepted 2.5-2.4?

Comment: you could use this expression, the delimiter must be whatever it is except a number
`"^[0-9]([^0-9][0-9])*$"`

Comment: @xxce10xx Yes my number can only be integer, so decimal can be delimiter too

Comment: so your question is how to identify files that are using delimiters that are not space, comma or line break? not sure I understood

Comment: @eusoubrasileiro I'm looking a regex to match a repeating pattern consisted of number + a delimiter. `"\d+"` will not work if the text is "12,34,56,78 9"

Comment: 789 should be interpreted as one number of two numbers 78, 9? your question body is far from clear.

Comment: consider reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @eusoubrasileiro I added more clarification, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following regular expression to obtain the fixed string that serves as a delimiter between consecutive strings of digits, or conclude that at least two delimiters are unequal. The delimiter string, provided there is a match, will be the contents of capture group 1. The attempted match will be unsuccessful if more than one distinct delimiter is present.

```
^\d+(\D+)\d+(?:\1\d+)*$
```

The string could then be split on the contents of capture group 1 to extract groups of consecutive digits.

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/Boq1b7/1/)<sup>2</sup>

If, for example, the string were:

```
1¯\_(ツ)_/¯2¯\_(ツ)_/¯3¯\_(ツ)_/¯4
```

the match would succeed and capture group 1 would contain `'¯\_(ツ)_/¯'`.

On the other hand, if the string were:

```
1¯\_(ツ)_/¯2¯\_(:-)_/¯3¯\_(ツ)_/¯4
```

the match would fail because not all delimiters are the same.

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^          : match beginning of string
\d+        : match 1+ digits
(\D+)      : match 1+ non-digits in capture group 1
\d+        : match 1+ digits
(?:\1\d+)  : match the content of capture group 1 followed by 1+ digits
             in a non-capture group
*          : execute the non-capture group 0+ times
$          : match end of string
```

<sup>1. I tested using the PCRE (PHP) regex engine, but a C++ regex engine would give the same results.</sup>

Comment: Not sure if simple number as `42` should be valid, but easy to handle anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Then I repeat my comment, you could use this expression, the delimiter could be anything except a number `"^[0-9]+([^0-9][0-9]+)*$"`

Comment: It didn't work. I tested with `12,34,56,78` on regexr.com but it didn't match

Comment: You are right, sorry, I had made a mistake, try it `^[0-9]+([^0-9][0-9]+)*$`

Comment: @xxce10xx Thanks, this worked if the ending is a number. How do you also match it if the ending is the delimiter?

Comment: `^[0-9]+([^0-9][0-9]+)*[^0-9]?$`

Comment: It breaks again also matching  `12,34 32 13`

Comment: what happens is that, the space is also a delimiter

Comment: It will also match something like this `1 2,3\34\1/3`

Comment: No, if it starts with the pattern of a number and a space, I want the following to also be followed by a number and a space. So a number and a comma should break it.

Comment: What you want is really complex, if we want the delimiter to be the same, you would have to check it in backend, or make a very large regular expression, something like this, but adding the delimiters one by one `^[0-9]+(([-][0-9]+)*|([,][0-9]+)*){1}$` there it only works with `","` and `"-"`, if you want you can add `";" "/" `...

Answer (score 0):

This is watching for anything except numbers :

```
[^\d]+
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/CJcmLc/1)

Comment: I don't have the answer to your question, but you can read about [regex backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html), that can match a text previously matched.

Comment: Example : `\d+([^\d]+)\d+(\1)` matches 2 consecutive same separators (test [here](https://regex101.com/r/y3phz4/1). I didn't manage to have an unlimited check for the line